# Cypress: is there an event listener for notifications in the app

Tags: dom-events, cypress

In principle, the app under test could throw at any time Error notifications (usually when something is not working as it should: server side). My problem is that my cypress test does not fail over such error messages.

Is it possible to configure a listener in cypress for such events? It would basically always listen if something like a message box pops up.

Eg. listening for:

```
cy.contains('[data-e2e-notification-message-text]', 'ERROR: ')
```

Answer (score 4):

You're talking about the difference between **active** and **passive** element checking.

Generally speaking, active waiting for the notification is better

```js
cy.contains('[data-e2e-notification-message-text]', 'ERROR: ', {timeout: 7000})
  .should('not.exist')
```

than passive waiting

```js
cy.on('notification', (message) => {   // NOT REAL CODE - for illustration
  if (message.includes('ERROR: ')) {
    throw 'Notification occurred'      // fail the test
  }
})
```

because the chain of events involves asynchronous call from the backend, which can vary in timing. If the test ends before the notification arrives, you get a **false positive test**.

---

You can set up an intercept if the action is request/response style, e.g

```js
cy.intercept(...).as('notification')         // listen
cy.get(button).click()                       // action
cy.wait('@notification')                     // assert
```

Add a stub if the live server is slow

```js
cy.intercept(url, { notification: 'Error: ' })          // immediately fake response
cy.get(button).click()                                          // action
cy.contains('[data-e2e-notification-message-text]', 'ERROR: ')  // assert
```

Or **don't explicitly wait**

```js
cy.intercept(url, (req) => {
  req.on('response', (res) => {
    if (res.body.includes('Error:')) {
      throw 'Notification of error'            // fail the test
    }
  })
cy.get(button).click()                                          // action
```

But also a chance of false positive result depending on timing.

---

If you did have a use case for periodic checking for an element, you could tap into the `command:end` event.

You can only do static (jQuery) DOM querying in an event handler (no `cy.()` commands).

```js
// after every command look for notification
Cypress.on('command:end', () => {
  const notification = Cypress.$('[data-e2e-notification-message-text]:contains(ERROR:)')
  if (notification.length) {
    throw 'Notification of error happened'    // fail the test
  }
})
```

Same caveat applies - this could be flaky if the test is faster than the notification.

Comment: Thank you for your very nice explanation. As far as I can see non of it really applies to what I am looking for. I can not wait for a notification, as a notification not necessarily appears.We have a flag which says when the page is completely loaded. I could use this, but that would defeat the async loading of the test and makes it slow as it would wait after each action.

Comment: Yes, I had trouble trying to understand that. So if the the notification appears, you want to fail the test - but if it does not appear within the test time frame the test passes - even though it may occur 100ms after the test ends?

Comment: Yes, the test should fail if an error message appears. The error message appears user actions, but the there is always a delay of many seconds. Which is why, if the error message appears, it has to fail. If the test is finished, it locks out and no message can appear anymore...